# Dual monitors on Ubuntu?

Tags: graphics, package-management, multiple-monitors, bluetooth

Simple things in Ubuntu often seem to require annoying, long google-hunts - however as a scientist, I love Ubuntu because complicated things are never harder than they need to be.  I'm looking to understand how certain problems arise and persist in Ubuntu, rather than to find actual fixes to the problems.

I used to connect to my Linux box remotely to use it, however I mostly use it now rather than Windows, so moved an ASUS 1920x1080 monitor onto it.  It detected the screen straight away and ran without any problems.  The graphics card is a Radeon HD4870 1GB, and I have a new Radeon HD7750 which will be added when I move to three monitors.  I am using the latest fglrx driver, as I also play a few games and do the odd bits of data visualisation.

I have since removed the ASUS and added 1920x1200 and 1920x1080 DELL monitors to it, intending to have the 1080 to the right of the 1200.  Addition of a second monitor has been problematic:

1. Ubuntu by default insists on overlapping (note: not cloning) the monitors, so they're both showing the workspace from (0,0), with the 1080-high monitor clipped at the bottom.  Changes to this via the KDE display manager get ignored and reverted without any error messages.
2. The AMD Catalyst "administrative" launcher shortcut asks me for the admin password endlessly, telling me that I've got it wrong each time I try.  I have to manually "gksudo amdcccle", then type in the exact same password in order to open Catalyst in "administrative" mode.
3. After changing the monitor settings in Catalyst, I am told that I have to reboot in order for my changes to take effect.  Even my Windows box doesn't have this requirement, and Windows seems to request reboots at every possible opportunity.

While I don't need help solving this problem (once I've tracked down where the config files have moved to in Ubuntu since I last had to do this manually), I am interested as to why the graphics side of Ubuntu is so incomplete.  Surely I'm not the only Ubuntu user who has a multi-monitor setup?

Another such problem occurred a few years ago, when I upgraded (from 8.xx to 9.xx I think, neither were betas).  On the old version, Bluetooth worked flawlessly.  On the new version, my OpenOffice suite had been replaced without consent by the virtually identical LibreOffice, and more annoyingly, my working Bluetooth drivers had been needlessly replaced by some that didn't work at all and caused crashes.  Do these new packages actually get tested at all before release?  Why do updates get released that completely replace software (with some other software, not an upgrade) without explicitly consenting the user first?

As a bonus, are there any distros out there that have graphics with comparable reliability to Windows and that put users' preferences first when updating?

Comment: This is really, really long.  I don't see where exactly you are asking a question except the sentance: "*I am interested as to why the graphics side of Ubuntu is so incomplete. Surely I'm not the only Ubuntu user who has a multi-monitor setup?*".  Unfortunately we can't really answer that.  My understanding is though, that it all depends on the graphics card manufacturer writing a good driver.